# How do I get mypy to recognize that an argument of a function needs to be a subclass of a particular base class?

Tags: python, static-analysis, type-hinting, mypy, duck-typing

How do I get `mypy` to recognize that an argument of a function needs to be a subclass of a particular base class? Consider the following:

```
# main.py
class A: ... 

class B(A):
  def f(self, x):
    print(x)

class C(A):
  def f(self, x):
    print(x, "in C")
```

```
# test.py
def call_f(instance):
  instance.f("Hello")

if __name__=="__main__":
  from main import B, C
  b = B()
  call_f(b)
  c = C()
  call_f(c)
```

As shown in `main.py`, all subclasses of `A` implement a method `f`. `call_f` in `test.py` takes an instance of one of the subclasses of `A` and calls this method. An example of this is shown in the `if __name__ == "__main__":` section of `test.py`.

One way to type hint the definition in `test.py` would be the following:

```
# test_typed.py
from typing import Union
from main import B, C

def call_f(instance: Union[B, C]) -> None:
  instance.f("Hello")

if __name__=="__main__":
  from main import B, C
  b = B()
  call_f(b)
  c = C()
  call_f(c)
```

However, the disadvantage here is that I have to keep adding every new subclass of `A` into the function annotation of `call_f` which seems  repetitive.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use `A` rather than `Union[B, C]`, since `B` and `C` are both instances of `A`?

Comment: Yes, since `A` has no `f` defined, it will result in an error with `mypy --strict`, namely `with_types\test.py:5: error: "A" has no attribute "f"`

Comment: If you want to enforce that every subclass of `A` has a function `f`, you could just define `f` in `A` and then raise a `NotImplementedError` in the function body. I don't see how you can enforce subclasses to implement `f` otherwise.

Comment: agree with @BrokenBenchmark. You almost certainly need _some_ abstract class that `B` and `C` subclass, whether that's `A` or another class, and then use that abstract class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that taking a stab at an answer isn't a bad idea at this point, since I have enough information from the comments.

You need to first enforce that `f` is implemented by subclasses of `A`. Otherwise, you could implement a subclass that doesn't implement `f`, and static typechecking would (rightfully) point out that there is nothing preventing that from occurring. You could use `Union[B, C]` if you only wanted some subclasses to implement `f`, but you've already stated that this is undesirable for extensibility reasons.

What you should do is have the function accept instances of the superclass `A`, and raise an error whenever `f` as defined in the superclass is invoked:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class A(ABC):
  @abstractmethod
  def f(self, x):
    raise NotImplementedError("This method should be defined in subclasses of A.") 

class B(A):
  def f(self, x):
    print(x)

class C(A):
  def f(self, x):
    print(x, "in C")
```

Then, `call_f()` would look like the following:

```py
def call_f(instance: A) -> None:
  instance.f("Hello")
```

Comment: I'll accept your answer, but would you mind explaining why you didn't suggest use of the `abc` module here?

Comment: Didn't know they existed until now. I'll revise shortly.